# JSON data, automatically converting integer data into datetime format

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

In HTTP post/put, some fields in the data sent as JSON are automatically converted to datetime format.

Nodejs: 6.11.3
Mongodb: 4.0.9
Angularjs: 1.5.5
Server: Ubuntu 16.04
Dev Server: MacOS Mojave

```
"code" : "9990226",
```

When the Nodejs API is put/post, the "code" field is transformed into datetime format as follows.

```
"code" : "Tue Aug 14 9990 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (+03)",
```

Request Code:

```
exports.PostErpData = function (erpInfo, callback) {

var args = {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + erpInfo.token},
    data: { header : { branch: erpInfo.headers.branch, seri: erpInfo.headers.seri, lines: erpInfo.headers.lines } }
};

var api = "/api/document/receipt";

var argsData = JSON.stringify(args.data);

client.post( erpInfo.erpSettings.url + api, args, function (data, response) {
    erpInfo.responseData = data;
    callback(null, erpInfo);

}).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("ERROR" + err);
    callback(err);
});

};
```

What can I do to keep the data I've sent here unchanged?

Comment: Is hard to tell if you don't share the code involved

Comment: Hi @f-CJ I have added a Request Code. Thanks

Comment: Apply two breakpoints in your app. First on the line where you are stringifying the object and second on the line where you are getting the response.

Check the difference between them. My assumption is that your API is returning the modified response.

Comment: That's just an idea, i'm not a mondoDb expert, but maybe mongoDb expect a UTC time format, but instead of rejecting your value it convert the Unix/Epoch time to UTC time and store it, have you tried to store it as simple string?

Comment: Hi @PratyushSharma Data is coming right up to HTTP post. But after the HTTP process, it turns into a datetime format. I checked it in debug mode. What is happening is automatically translated during the http post process.

Comment: Hi @Nil The data to be saved after the HTTP transaction comes in this way. That's why mongodb is direct recording this way. I checked it in debug mode. It's not related to Mongodb post It converts automatically in http post. I didn't find out how to stop it.

Comment: You should check your API code for this. In case it is a third party API which you do not have control of then check their documentation for the type of field expected in the data. It may happen that 'code' is expected as a number instead of a string and if a string is present than it would take it as a date time format.

Comment: @PratyushSharma I'm the one who wrote the API. I'm using a Mongoose model. The type of this field is set to "String" and remains as "String" when it is converted to datetime format.

Comment: A string is not converted to date time format until its explicitly done. I would recommend you to check your API code and see which fields are getting affected and why. You can also share your API code here.

Comment: Hi Everybody, Problem solved. Thanks to everyone who commented. Based on the comments, I checked the API codes again. A parameter added by the previous developer friend is causing it.